# Is every DDR4 same?

Tags: laptop, memory

I am going to buy a ram online.  My laptop supports DDR4 ram. So if a purchase a DDR4 Ram will it be comparible with my laptop or every laptop has different type of ram even if they have same DDR type?

Comment: Surely there are different types of DDR4.  Obviously there can be different capacities.  I would also definitely expect different speeds to be one factor that can be different.

Comment: Then how to identify which is compatible with my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

No, absolutely not. RAM differs in a lot of ways besides just the interface access type.

Package type, [CAS latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency), ECC / no-ECC, buffered vs. non-buffered, how many RAM modules (actual chips on the DIMM) on a stick, etc. All these things can affect if RAM will work in a particular system.

Google your laptop and "RAM upgrade" and see some example SODIMM upgrade kits. Read the fine print in the ad, and you will find out the specific types you can use. Most north bridge chipsets allow RAM with varying CAS latency, but never support mixing and matching ECC / non-ECC - for instance. The good news is laptop memory has many less variations than servers and desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Use an online RAM upgrade helper, such as [Crucial's](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner) or [Kingston's](https://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/Options). Just input your PC's name, model etc. or run an app provided by those sites. As @EdH states, there are many parameters that decide if RAM is acceptable for your device.

Comment: thanks. Just one more thing. Is it better to have two 8GB rams or a single 16GB ram or it does not make a difference?

Comment: It depends on the machine... some require two cards, some don't. If your PC accepts a single 16 GB card, then that allows later upgrade in the second slot.